# How to create a Javascript Arrayfrom dom element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a list-view

```
<ul class="list-view">
    <li><span>root</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Child1
                    <ul><li>Chlid11</li></ul>
            </li>
            <li>Child2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Chlid21</li>
                        <li>Chlid22</li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Child3
                    <ul>
                        <li>Chlid31</li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>
```

I was asked in an interview to write a Json representation of the above HTML element and print true if the searched child exsist in tha JSon

For example:if I enter CHild21 then answer should be true

Please help me out I am new to JSON

Thanks

Comment: Forget JSON for a moment. Think about how you would represent the necessary data as a JavaScript object. That will get you 99% of the way there, since JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". :)

Comment: actually you are right I was not able to create the JavaScript array . with from the list . if I can get that then creating json is fairly simple

Answer (score 0):

Above format of DOM is XML. So any XML to JSON parser should do I think.

Here is a specific library for DOM to JSON:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JsonML